# Select every other row that has a specific class

Tags: css

I have a simple table structure

```
<table class="striped">
    <tr class="parent"><td></td></tr>
    <tr class="parent"><td></td></tr>
    <tr class="parent"><td></td></tr>
    <tr class="parent"><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

I can easily add CSS:

```
.striped tbody tr.parent:nth-of-type(odd) { background:red; }
```

The trouble is when you click one of these parent `<tr>` rows it will expand and add an additional `<tr>` detail row such as below:

```
<table class="striped">
    <tr class="parent"><td></td></tr>
    **<tr class="detail"><td></td></tr>**
    <tr class="parent"><td></td></tr>
    <tr class="parent"><td></td></tr>
    <tr class="parent"><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Is there a pure CSS way to keep just the ***original*** striping? [Here is a codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYzwLy) to show what is happening to the two tables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the option of changing the HTML slightly, you could use multiple explicit `<tbody>` elements and insert the child element inside the same `<tbody>` as the parent. This actually makes semantic sense as well as it groups the parent with its child.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody

> multiple `<tbody>` elements are permitted (if consecutive), allowing the data-rows in long tables to be divided into different sections, each separately formatted as needed

E.g.

```css
.striped tbody:nth-of-type(odd) .parent { background:red; }
```

```html
<table class="striped">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="parent"><td>Stuff</td></tr>
        <tr class="child"><td>child</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody><tr class="parent"><td>Stuff</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr class="parent"><td>Stuff</td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr class="parent"><td>Stuff</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @JonHarding yup, added reference to answer

Answer (score 2):

Is there only going to be one single `.detail` element at any given time?

If so, you could “reset” the background for the TR following that element, like this:

```css
.striped tbody tr.parent:nth-of-type(odd) { background:red; }
.striped tbody tr.detail ~ tr.parent:nth-of-type(even) { background:red; }
.striped tbody tr.detail ~ tr.parent:nth-of-type(odd) { background:none; }
```

```html
<table class="striped">
    <tr class="parent"><td>A</td></tr>
    <tr class="detail"><td>inserted</td></tr>
    <tr class="parent"><td>B</td></tr>
    <tr class="parent"><td>C</td></tr>
    <tr class="parent"><td>D</td></tr>
    <tr class="parent"><td>E</td></tr>
    <tr class="parent"><td>F</td></tr>
    <tr class="parent"><td>G</td></tr>
</table>
```

Since this inserted table row changes the “index” of all following TR by one, making the *even* ones following this details rows have a red background will continue the striping in the “right” way. (And the background for following *odd* rows has to be “nulled”, otherwise those would still have a red background from the first rule.)

Of course, as soon as you might have more than one `.detail` row inserted into the table, it won’t work that simple any more.

Comment: unfortunately you could click as many details open as you'd like. I'm thinking I'm going to need JS to tackle this one (No jquery ;) )

Answer (score 0):

The  problem you have there is `nth-of-type` searching for the type. It counts the `detail` also, because it has the same type as the `parent`s.

My suggestion: remake the `<td>`s. One would be `<parent>`s, another would be `<detail>`s.

```css
parent:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background:red;
}

parent, detail{
    display:table-row;
}
tr{
    display:table-cell;
}
```

```html
<table class="striped">
    <tr><parent>one</parent></tr>
    <tr><detail>detail</detail></tr>
    <tr><parent>two</parent></tr>
    <tr><parent>three</parent></tr>
    <tr><parent>four</parent></tr>
</table>
```

This way it's going work.